# CSS Grid place items out of order in display: contents wrapper

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to place descendants in a root grid while they're wrapped in a container with `display: contents`.

The problem I'm having is one element is not being placed in the correct location in the grid:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 80ch;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

p {
  margin-block-start: 0px;
}

as-question {
  --font-size: 12pt;
  --spacing: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  font-size: var(--font-size, 12pt);
  gap: var(--spacing, 8px);
  grid-template-columns: [question-number-start] 10mm [question-number-end part-number-start question-content-start] 1.75rem [part-number-end part-content-start subpart-number-start] 1.75rem [subpart-number-end subpart-content-start] auto [part-content-end subpart-content-end question-content-end marks-start] 2rem [marks-end question-end];
}
as-question:before {
  grid-column: question-number-start/question-number-end;
  content: "1.";
  counter-reset: part subpart;
}
as-question .content {
  display: contents;
}
as-question > div.content > :not(as-part):not(as-subpart) {
  grid-column: question-content-start/question-content-end;
}
as-question as-marks {
  grid-column: marks-start/marks-end;
}
as-question as-part {
  display: contents;
}
as-question as-part:before {
  counter-reset: subpart;
  counter-increment: part;
  grid-column: part-number-start/part-number-end;
  content: "(" counter(part, lower-alpha) ")";
  text-align: right;
}
as-question as-part > div.content > :not(as-subpart) {
  grid-column: part-content-start/part-content-end;
}
as-question as-part as-marks {
  color: red;
}
as-question as-subpart {
  display: contents;
}
as-question as-subpart:before {
  counter-increment: subpart;
  grid-column: subpart-number-start/subpart-number-end;
  content: "(" counter(subpart, lower-roman) ")";
  text-align: right;
}
as-question as-subpart > div.content * {
  grid-column: subpart-content-start/subpart-content-end;
}
as-question as-subpart as-marks {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<as-question>
    <div class='content'>
      <p>This is some question content</p>
      <as-part>
        <as-marks>2</as-marks>
        <div class='content'>
          <p>Part: How can I not be pushed down?</p>
          <as-subpart>
            <as-marks>1</as-marks>
            <div class='content'>
              <p>Subpart</p>
            </div>
          </as-subpart>
          <as-subpart>
            <as-marks>1</as-marks>
            <div class='content'>
              <p>Subpart</p>
            </div>
          </as-subpart>
        </div>
      </as-part>
      <as-part>
        <as-marks>6</as-marks>
        <div class='content'>
          <p>Part</p>
          <as-subpart>
            <as-marks>4</as-marks>
            <div class='content'>
              <p>Subpart</p>
            </div>
          </as-subpart>
          <as-subpart>
            <as-marks>2</as-marks>
            <div class='content'>
              <p>Subpart</p>
            </div>
          </as-subpart>
        </div>
      </as-part>
    </div>
  </as-question>
```

Whenever I place a `<as-marks>{number}</as-marks>` element before a `<div class='content'>` element (which has `display: contents;`), the first child of `<div class="content">` gets pushed down to the next row (see image below).

[image: descendants in wrong place]

Is there a way I can make sure the first child of `<div class='content'>` is placed on the first line next to the marks?

I can go back to using grids within grids within grids, but this seemed cleaner. `subgrid` can't come soon enough.

[Codepen for testing](https://codepen.io/Brent-Parker-the-sans/pen/bGOoaax)

If you're curious why the HTML is structured in this way, it is because I'm trying to use Prosemirror with custom NodeViews and this is how Prosemirror structures the resulting HTML.

Comment: Please include your demo code in the question itself (with compiled CSS) so that your post doesn't rely on third-party resources. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Fixed the demo code. I left the codepen because it is editable and it might help other users test their solutions before hopefully adding an answer. The question does not rely on it; it's merely a useful, optional tool.

Comment: Nothing wrong with leaving a codepen, jsFiddle, etc. as a supplementary resource.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

**1. grid auto placement algorithm**

The `<div class="content">` item is pushed to the next line because there's nothing altering its natural placement in the grid.

In other words, it's flowing naturally to the next line because, in the HTML, it comes after the pseudo-element and after the `<as-marks>` element.

So unless you tell it to render on a certain row (e.g., `grid-row: 2`), the [grid auto placement algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-placement-algo) controls.

**2. `grid-auto-flow: dense`**

Fortunately, the grid authors foresaw this situation and implemented a feature to solve the problem.

With [`grid-auto-flow: dense`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-auto-flow-property) the algorithm tries to fill empty spaces earlier in the grid.

Add that line of code your grid container.

Here's your code with one modification (and compiled CSS):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 80ch;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

p {
  margin-block-start: 0px;
}

as-question {
  --font-size: 12pt;
  --spacing: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  font-size: var(--font-size, 12pt);
  gap: var(--spacing, 8px);
  grid-template-columns: [question-number-start] 10mm [question-number-end part-number-start question-content-start] 1.75rem [part-number-end part-content-start subpart-number-start] 1.75rem [subpart-number-end subpart-content-start] auto [part-content-end subpart-content-end question-content-end marks-start] 2rem [marks-end question-end];
  grid-auto-flow: dense; /* NEW */
}
as-question:before {
  grid-column: question-number-start/question-number-end;
  content: "1.";
  counter-reset: part subpart;
}
as-question .content {
  display: contents;
}
as-question > div.content > :not(as-part):not(as-subpart) {
  grid-column: question-content-start/question-content-end;
}
as-question as-marks {
  grid-column: marks-start/marks-end;
}
as-question as-part {
  display: contents;
}
as-question as-part:before {
  counter-reset: subpart;
  counter-increment: part;
  grid-column: part-number-start/part-number-end;
  content: "(" counter(part, lower-alpha) ")";
  text-align: right;
}
as-question as-part > div.content > :not(as-subpart) {
  grid-column: part-content-start/part-content-end;
}
as-question as-part as-marks {
  color: red;
}
as-question as-subpart {
  display: contents;
}
as-question as-subpart:before {
  counter-increment: subpart;
  grid-column: subpart-number-start/subpart-number-end;
  content: "(" counter(subpart, lower-roman) ")";
  text-align: right;
}
as-question as-subpart > div.content * {
  grid-column: subpart-content-start/subpart-content-end;
}
as-question as-subpart as-marks {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <as-question>
    <div class='content'>
      <p>This is some question content</p>
      <as-part>
        <as-marks>2</as-marks>
        <div class='content'>
          <p>Part: How can I not be pushed down?</p>
          <as-subpart>
            <as-marks>1</as-marks>
            <div class='content'>
              <p>Subpart</p>
            </div>
          </as-subpart>
          <as-subpart>
            <as-marks>1</as-marks>
            <div class='content'>
              <p>Subpart</p>
            </div>
          </as-subpart>
        </div>
      </as-part>
      <as-part>
        <as-marks>6</as-marks>
        <div class='content'>
          <p>Part</p>
          <as-subpart>
            <as-marks>4</as-marks>
            <div class='content'>
              <p>Subpart</p>
            </div>
          </as-subpart>
          <as-subpart>
            <as-marks>2</as-marks>
            <div class='content'>
              <p>Subpart</p>
            </div>
          </as-subpart>
        </div>
      </as-part>
    </div>
  </as-question>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `<as-marks>` element needs to stay in line with top of the part/subpart children. Using `grid-auto-flow: dense` will place them in the wrong rows.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. Because `grid-auto-flow: dense` is applying to all grid items. Perhaps fill that empty cell on the first line with an invisible item, so that `<as-marks>` stays put.